# VSTS 2010 - how to validate incorrect updates to a workitem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We are using VSTS2010 for logging bugs. There are weekly builds happening and the QA/DEV updates bugs to fixed/open based on build numbers.

Since there are weekly builds happening and each build has a different number, there are chances for QA/DEV to set incorrect build numbers in fixed build/tested build number.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to validate the build number values based on some parameters like date of fixes?
2. Is it possible to show approrpiate messages for the validations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a build-in way to validate the build number against parameters.

At the moment I can see two possible solutions for your problem, depending on the structure and your possibilities to change the system:

1. Minimize the set of build numbers to choose. You could change the source list of the build field to show a list with less entries, like only the entries of the last week/month. That would need a little script, that changes your globallist. Of course that only works, if no one else needs to select older builds.
2. Create an invisible custom control and add it to your bug work item. Inside the custom control you have almost any freedom to change or validate date and show them the way you want to. But you would need to develop it and install it on every PC that needs to use it.